# Create object in flask

Tags: python, database, flask

So basicaly I have this class:

```
class Grupa(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'grupa'

    id_grupy = db.Column(db.BigInteger, db.Sequence('grupa_seq'), primary_key=True)
    nr_semestru = db.Column(db.SmallInteger)
    rodzaj = db.Column(db.String(5))
    nr_grupy = db.Column(db.SmallInteger)
    dzien_tyg = db.Column(db.SmallInteger)
    godz_rozp = db.Column(db.SmallInteger)
    ilosc_godz = db.Column(db.SmallInteger)
    czestatliwosc = db.Column(db.SmallInteger)
    id_prowadzacego = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('prowadzacy.id_prowadzacego'))
    id_przedmiotu = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('przedmiot.id_przedmiotu'))
    id_sali = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('sala.id_sali'))
    id_specjalnosci = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('specjalnosc.id_specjalnosci'))
    id_studia = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('studia.id_studia'))

    oferty = db.relationship('Oferta', backref='grupa')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Grupa(grupa={self.id_grupy!r})>'.format(self=self)
```

Now using `flask` I would like to create an object of it and add it to the `database`. I found the next example of:

```
from yourapp import User
me = User('admin', 'admin@example.com')
db.session.add(me)
db.session.commit()
```

The problem I have is 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmMqr.jpg)

To be hones I was expecting giving params like "`id_grupy`" and so on and I have this. What is this classname and bases here?

P.S. That was really helpfull but now I got diffrent problem.
I go in for over my dataframe to extract it row by row and then add it to my database and there is that weird error

```
    for row in df.iterrows():
        dzien, godz, ilosc, tyg, id_naucz, id_sala, id_prz, rodz, grupa, id_st, sem, id_spec = row
```

As You see im trying to put this values from each row and error i get is :

dzien, godz, ilosc, tyg, id_naucz, id_sala, id_prz, rodz, grupa, id_st, sem, id_spec = row
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 12, got 2)

Which is weird I just gave 12 values for him, why he got only 2 of them?

Answer (score 0):

What you did is nice, but you need to add a `__init__` function to your `Grupa` class in order to give attributes you want to your object :

```
def __init__(self, id_grupy, nr_semestru, rodzaj, ...):
    self.id_grupy = id_grupy
    self.nr_semetru = nr_semetru
    self.rodzaj = rodzaj
    ...
```

(see an example [here](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/models/))

See ya !